# How can I analyze small sample?

Tags: survey, small-sample

I want to use multivariate OLS on a sample size of 33, but I read somewhere that the rule of thumb is that there should be at least 30 observations to fit one covariate. I want to add around 5 covariates...does this mean I can't use multiple regression?

Comment: Do you really mean "multivariate" (vector-valued responses) or just "multiple" (more than one explanatory variables) regression?

Comment: Also, why do you think you need to use "multivariate OLS?"  I prefer people tell us a bit about their research objectives and then we'll suggest some appropriate 
approaches.

Comment: @whuber I meant multiple!

Comment: @StatsStudent I added the objectives -- thank you

Comment: @user2298759 can you give us a bit more information?  How was your data collected?  What type of data is this?

Comment: @StatsStudent Just added!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "best" random sampling?  Do you mean simple random sampling?  Also, how is your independent variable measured?  In other words, how is satisfaction measured in your survey?  Did you ask people to rate their satisfaction?  It's important we know how satisfaction is $measured$.  Also, have you defined your population yet?  What is it?  All people in a country?  Only people receiving services at one of the agencies (all agencies?)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87812/discussion-between-user2298759-and-statsstudent).

Answer (score 2):

I would say you have a couple issues here.

First, yes, your sample is too small for so many covariates. You have a lot of danger of overfitting. There are various rules of thumb - I've often seen 10 per covariate - but it partly depend on how the different IVs relate to each other.

Second, since the DV is likert scaled, you probably don't want OLS (linear) regression. I'd look at ordinal logistic regression. However, this makes for even stricter limits on sample size per covariate.

Third, you don't have a simple random sample; you got 33 people from 8 agencies. So, it's not a simple random sample from a population. It's not completely clear what it actually is (cluster sampling, probably).

Comment: Given the complications, I think you might want to hire an expert, but I think you  are going to need a bigger sample.

Comment: +1 - Agreed Peter.  I raised all of these issues with the OP in the extended chat.  The OP seems to want to use OLS with many independent variables despite having a likert-scaled dependent variable collected from a multi-staged, sort-of-cluster sample with unequal probabilities of selection without using weights, survey design variables, finite population corrections, or any knowledge of the actual size of the population.  At some point one has to wonder why any data was collected at all instead of just making up numbers...

Comment: Thanks   ..... and thanks for the positive mention in the chat.

Answer (score 2):

Rules of thumb about the number of observations per covariate are generally pretty useless. They're typically based on ideal designs and balance as the best possible scenario, since the worst possible scenario can be arbitrarily bad at any sample size.

The stupid suggestion is: go collect more data. But money, time, grant cycles etc. often demand otherwise. It is a shame, because reporting underpowered analyses in the grand scheme of things *increase* type 1 errors... more people are publishing incomplete research!

It helps to step back and consider what the impact of the two approaches is:

Omit important confounding variable(s) from analysis and obtain biased results. Over adjust the analysis and lose precision. Under adjusted analyses can be imprecise as well, it depends how much the $R^2$ improves as a result of adjustment, since any adjustment variable has at least some precision power.

One possible approach to this problem is presenting the results of *all* models entering the covariate(s) one at a time into the model in a stepwise fashion. This is not an attempt to reproduce stepwise selection, but rather to jointly consider the impact of adjustment to alleviate bias in spite of the high variance of a properly adjusted analysis. You can follow the adjusted effect for the main exposure and qualitatively describe how it is impacted by the subsequent addition of covariates.

Typically the underpowered analysis is the most correct, and you can remark on the width and center of the confidence intervals to point to where the science will lead you.